# control the digit display of fit summary after regression

Tags: r

How can I control the digit display of the `summary(fit)`, now it display too many digits after the decimal. Tried to use `options(digits=3)`,but it does not work

```
> fit <- lm(y ~ x1 + x2 + x3)
> summary(fit) # show results
```

Answer (score 6):

```
fit <- lm(mpg~wt,mtcars)
print(summary(fit),digits=2)

# Call:
# lm(formula = mpg ~ wt, data = mtcars)

# Residuals:
#    Min     1Q Median     3Q    Max 
#  -4.54  -2.36  -0.13   1.41   6.87 

# Coefficients:
#             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
# (Intercept)    37.29       1.88    19.9   <2e-16 ***
# wt             -5.34       0.56    -9.6    1e-10 ***
# ---
# Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

# Residual standard error: 3 on 30 degrees of freedom
# Multiple R-squared:  0.75,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.74 
# F-statistic:  91 on 1 and 30 DF,  p-value: 1.3e-10
```

Comment: Is there a way to make this work with just the coefficients matrix?

Comment: `print(summary(fit)$coefficients,digits=2)` or `print(coefficients(summary(fit)),digits=2)`

Comment: Ah. Thanks. I think I had trouble making it work when compiling an Rmd file to HTML, but it clearly works on the coefficient matrix when just running the code in R.