# Why does "digits" argument not affect output of print(summary(fit))?

Tags: r, lm, summary

I found the solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22670709/control-the-digit-display-of-fit-summary-after-regression). If I run the `mtcars` example, digits are displayed as expected.
But when I use the [Avertising dataset](http://www-bcf.usc.edu/~gareth/ISL/data.html) and the follwing script, the `digits` argument does not have any effect:

```
path <- "path_to_adverising_csv/"
file <- "Advertising.csv"
filename <- paste0(path, file)
advertising <- read.csv(filename, header = TRUE)
names(advertising)

advertising_fit <- lm(sales~TV+radio+newspaper, data = advertising)
print(summary(advertising_fit), digits = 2)
```

Output:

```
Call:
lm(formula = sales ~ TV + radio + newspaper, data = advertising)

Residuals:
   Min     1Q Median     3Q    Max 
-8.828 -0.891  0.242  1.189  2.829 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  2.93889    0.31191    9.42   <2e-16 ***
TV           0.04576    0.00139   32.81   <2e-16 ***
radio        0.18853    0.00861   21.89   <2e-16 ***
newspaper   -0.00104    0.00587   -0.18     0.86    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 1.69 on 196 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.897, Adjusted R-squared:  0.896 
F-statistic:  570 on 3 and 196 DF,  p-value: <2e-16
```

Do I miss something obvious?

Comment: I tried with digits=2, 1 and 0 and the output changes. But indeed it doen't change on every number. Strange behaviour.

Comment: More, when you look at `?summary.lm`, digits should be the number of significant digits, like when you use `signif()`, but in fat it is the number of decimal places like when you use `round()`

Comment: I suspect it defaults to printing more than the specified number of digits because the effects of your `TV` and `newspaper` variables are so small / contain zeroes after the decimal point. If you estimate the model with only `radio` as an explanatory variable, `digits = 2` works as expected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under the hood, this is calling `printCoefMat` to print the coefficient matrix *nicely*. `digits` is passed to this function where the help states

> **digits** minimum number of significant digits to be used for most numbers.

Note 'most numbers'.

Looking at the source, this will eventually call `format` on a vector containing the rounded values absolute value of coefficients and their standard errors with the  passing same `digits` argument value.

From the help for `format`

> **digits**
>
> how many significant digits are to be used for numeric and complex x. The default, NULL, uses getOption("digits"). This is a suggestion: enough decimal places will be used so that the smallest (in magnitude) number has this many significant digits, and also to satisfy nsmall. (For the interpretation for complex numbers see signif.) see signif.)

Therefore, as you have enough decimal points for the smallest of the coefficients and their standard errors to have sufficient significant digits.

In this case it is the coefficient for `newspaper`.

Comment: Ok, but as I can do `print(summary(fit),digits=0)` for the mtcars example, I would expect `print(summary(advertising_fit), digits = 3)` to work?